# Question about normal subgroups of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a group $G$ and two normal subgroups $N_1, N_2 \unlhd G$ with $N_1 \leq N_2$.

> Is it true that $G/N_2 \leq G/N_1$?

Comment: If $\leq$ means subgroup then it is true.

Comment: What do you mean by $N_1 \le N_2$?

Comment: Hint: See what happens when one of the subgroups is trivial.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't get this hint

Comment: Then you seem to mean something different with $\leq $ than the usual meaning of "subgroup of".

Comment: @user204667 Maybe a more striking way to put it: Is every quotient of $G$ (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @Hoot No. Ok, now I get it. I got confused as I thought the answer was yes, given all the other replies to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of what is mentioned in the comments, consider $G=\mathbb Z$, $N_1=\{0\}$, $N_2=2\mathbb Z$. $G/N_1\cong \mathbb Z$ and $G/N_2\cong\mathbb Z_2$, and neither of these groups is isomorphic to a subgroup of the other.